# Automatically add Gettext to all japanese texts in all php files in a directory

Tags: php, utf-8, gettext, php-gettext

I have some 500 php files which contain some Japanese texts that are to translated. I want to add gettext to all those japanese texts. How can I add it automatically in all php files

Answer (score 0):

As a starter you can extract all strings:

```
$ find DIRECTORY -name '*.php*' >POTFILES
$ xgettext -a --files-from=POTFILES
```

That results in a file `messages.po` in the current directory, containing all possibly translatable strings.  When you open `messages.po` in a PO editor like emacs (key `s`) or Poedit (check the docs), you can directly visit the source file from the PO file.

Adding `gettext()` calls automatically is not supported because you will normally have a lot of false positives.